# li 100% width inside ui with scroll

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list with horizontal scrollbar and I need change color of list items, but if **I will scroll** I won't see styles on items because width of items are not covering full list width.

[image: Example]

```css
ul {
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
}


li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sdjaflkjasd lfkjsadjf lksadjf ljadslfj lasdjfl jasf</li>
  <li>asdf asdf dsaf</li>
  <li>sdf dsaf dsa</li>
  <li>sd afdsa fdsaf </li>
  <li>sad fadsf sad</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: inline-block + min-width:100%

Comment: TemaniAfif, unfortunately, if you scroll a bit and hover on short element you will see the same result.

Comment: add `display: grid;` to ul

Comment: @TemaniAfif, https://www.dropbox.com/s/p718hs3tm6qcnde/Screenshot%202020-10-12%20at%2023.29.07.png?dl=0

Comment: @TemaniAfif, hmm, `display: grid;` looks good, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:grid`

```css
ul {
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sdjaflkjasd lfkjsadjf lksadjf ljadslfj lasdjfl jasf</li>
  <li>asdf asdf dsaf</li>
  <li>sdf dsaf dsa</li>
  <li>sd afdsa fdsaf </li>
  <li>sad fadsf sad</li>
</ul>
```